# Restrict S3 Bucket Access by Referer (domain) - Static Website Hosting - Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website hosted on S3 and Cloudfront as distribution.

I would like the bucket to be only accessed by selected domains. I followed multiple AWS documentation files that point that I should forward **Referer** header, but I can't get it working since I always get **403** error.

The bucket is configured to be public:

```
   FrontendBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          IndexDocument: index.html
          ErrorDocument: 404.html
          RoutingRules: ${file(./redirects.json)}
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedHeaders: ["*"]
              AllowedMethods: ["GET"]
              AllowedOrigins: ["*"]
              Id: "OpenCors"
              MaxAge: "3600"
```

Then, in order to forward the Referer header, I have created Cloudfront Cache Policy and Cloudfront Origin Request Policy:

```
CloudfrontCachePolicy:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::CachePolicy
      Properties:
        CachePolicyConfig:
          Name: cache-policy
          Comment: Cache Optimized Policy (forward  referer and query string)
          DefaultTTL: 86400
          MaxTTL: 31536000
          MinTTL: 1
          ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
            EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: true
            EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: true
            CookiesConfig:
              CookieBehavior: none
            HeadersConfig:
              HeaderBehavior: whitelist
              Headers:
                - Referer
            QueryStringsConfig:
              QueryStringBehavior: all



CloudfronOriginRequestPolicy:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::OriginRequestPolicy
      Properties:
        OriginRequestPolicyConfig:
          Name: origin-request-policy
          Comment: Origin Request Policy (forward referer  query string)
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior: none
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: whitelist
            Headers:
              - Referer
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: all
```

Then this is my Cloudfront distribution:

```
   CloudfrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      DependsOn: [FrontendBucket]
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Enabled: true
          Comment: "(${self:provider.stage}-${opt:lang})"
          Aliases: ${self:custom.domainCondition.${self:provider.stage}.${opt:lang}, self:custom.domainCondition.other}
          ViewerCertificate:
            AcmCertificateArn: "${self:custom.certificateCondition.${self:provider.stage}.${opt:lang}, self:custom.certificateCondition.other.${opt:lang}}"
            MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2018
            SslSupportMethod: sni-only
          Origins:
            - Id:
                Ref: FrontendBucket
              DomainName: "${self:custom.frontendBucketName}.s3-website-${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com"
              CustomOriginConfig:
                OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
                HTTPPort: 80
                HTTPSPort: 443
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            TargetOriginId:
              Ref: FrontendBucket
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
            Compress: true
            CachePolicyId:
              Ref: CloudfrontCachePolicy
            OriginRequestPolicyId:
              Ref: CloudfronOriginRequestPolicy
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            CachedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: "origin-request"
                LambdaFunctionARN: ${cf.us-east-1:my-website-cle-${self:provider.stage}.RequestCLELambdaFunctionQualifiedArn}
              - EventType: "origin-response"
                LambdaFunctionARN: ${cf.us-east-1:my-website-cle-${self:provider.stage}.ResponseCLELambdaFunctionQualifiedArn}
```

As you can see, there is **Origin Request Lambda@Edge** assigned. I am trying to log `event.Records[0].cf.request.headers` there, but I can't find the **referer header**.

And finally this the Bucket Policy:

```
   OnlyDomainAccessPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket:
          Ref: FrontendBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Sid: "Allow access to the bucket only from MiracleMill website"
              Effect: Deny
              Action: ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion"]
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.frontendBucketName}/*"
              Principal: "*"
              Condition:
               StringNotLike:
                  aws:Referer:
                   [
                      "http://www.example.com/*",
                      "https://example.com/*",
                    ]
//at this point this should work since the bucket is public but I have also added specific Allow
            - Sid: "Allow access to the bucket only from MiracleMill website"
              Effect: Allow
              Action: ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion"]
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.frontendBucketName}/*"
              Principal: "*"
              Condition:
                StringLike:
                  aws:Referer:
                    [
                      "http://www.www.example.com/*",
                      "https://www.example.com/*",
                    ]
```

Comment: **Side-note:** Using `referer` to protect access to objects is very weak security. It is quite easy to fake the `referer` field. Do not use this as a method of protecting confidential data. Instead, use an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.

Comment: I am fine with that, I just can't forward the Referer Header. It does not show up in Lambda Edge.